# LNK1104 cannot open .h file

Tags: c++, opengl

I have looked it up and I from what they say, I must have:

1: wrong path.
I will try to prove this wrong.

the path to a glfw3.h file is " `A:\projects\3d fresh start\OpenGLRoot\External Resources\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include\GLFW\glfw3.h`"

inside of "Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories" I have "`A:\projects\3d fresh start\OpenGLRoot\External Resources\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include`".

the code for the include is:

`#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`

I can supply the whole page of code if needed.

As you can see, in the include folder, in the GLFW folder is the file.

Perhaps I needed to put `"quotation marks"` instead of `<brackets>`, but i tried both.

2: I have the wrong version, 32 vs 64 bit

I do not believe so.

This is a picture of the config manager which says 64 bit. So I am using 64 bit.
[image]

The grandparent folder containing `glfw3.h` says "WIN64" in its name. so i would assume that it is 64 bit.

So is it safe to say that versions are all correct?

3: library might have dependencies that have not been installed.

I maybe this is the issue? I'm trying to follow a tutorial, so it should work.

4: permissions issue.

I ran Visual studio as Administrator via a right click. wouldn't this solve that?

Comment: The picuture of the config manager says that you are changing the settings for a 64 bit build. But it does not say that you are **performing** a 64 bit build. If you are actually performing a 32 bit build these settings would be ignored.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full command line? It is under "command line" in the project properties. Also show the full output under the build/output pane. Are you sure you're building x64/Debug?

Comment: Please quote your entire error message. LNK1104 is a linker error message, and linkers never read header files, so the error does not make sense. If your linker is really trying to read a header file you must have your settings seriously wrong.

Comment: Understanding how C++ programs are built, compilers vs linkers, source files vs header files, object files vs library files, include paths, library paths, 32 bit vs 64 bit, release vs debug etc etc. is a significant hurdle for new programmers. You are clearly making a mistake somewhere. It's not completely obvious what it is from the information above but you do seem confused about the difference between a header file and a library file.

Comment: Thank you John. I was assuming that because the file in question was a ".h" file, that it must be a problem in C/C++ in settings. But actually the problem was in Linker. I wrote `glfw3.h` instead of `glfw3.lib`. The Problem is resolved. It compiled and ran. thank you very much.

Comment: so... should you make an "answer" to this question so that it can be marked as solved. I guess I could answer my own question, but you were the one who helped me.